# Lookup a company by either name or ticker in a Microsoft Access form

Tags: ms-access

I can't get my Microsoft Access form to match the Company Name to the Company Ticker. If I select a company from my combo box, the ticker does NOT correspond to the company's actual ticker. For example, when I select "Altria Group" the ticker should be "MO", but I'm getting the ticker "cr" which doesn't correspond to the company selected.

Combo box code.

```
SELECT tblCompanies.CompanyName
FROM tblCompanies
ORDER BY tblCompanies.CompanyName;
```

See my table of Companies and my form below.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is form RecordSource a query? Edit question to show SQL statement.

Comment: @June7 Not sure what you mean by RecordSource being a query. I added a screenshot of the "Company Name" combo box properties. I'd assume once you pull up a record, the relevant information would just populate automatically.

Comment: @June7 The Record Source for this form is "tblCompanies". I attached a screenshot

Comment: A form RecordSource can be a table, query, or SQL statement. How does selecting item in combobox retrieve record? Post code. Does tblCompanies have autonumber primary key? Why is textbox ControlSource an expression with = sign and not just bound to field?

Comment: I edited question to include combobox code. The table tblCompanies has an autonumber primary key and I changed the ticker to say textbox to [Ticker] and just Ticker, but it didn't make a difference :(

Comment: You provided combobox RowSource, not code that selects or finds record for display on form.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I normally do this is to use two combo boxes in the form's header for navigation - one to show the company name, and one to show the company code. Each of these are unbound, column count set to 2, and the first column width set to 0, so it is not shown, and the RowSource would look like:

```
SELECT CompanyID, CompanyName
FROM tblCompanies
ORDER BY CompanyName
```

Then, in the AfterUpdate event:

```
Private Sub cboCompanyNameSearch_AfterUpdate()
    Me.RecordsetClone.FindFirst "CompanyID=" & Me!cboCompanyNameSearch
    Me.Bookmark = Me.RecordsetClone.Bookmark
End Sub
```

In the body of the form, you would have text boxes to actually show the company name and other description, so that this information can be edited if required.

Regards,